# Backbone JS view render not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In the below code, unable to render 'TodoList'. Seems like fetching taking time and so displaying '`0`' and `<div id=​"demo">​</div>​` before only.

and Iam not sure why '`3`' and '`Descriptions`' got displayed later. All I need is to display '`Descriptions List`' in the page. Iam able to get data from server but somehow not able to display as soon as the data arrived. Please tell me what changes need to do in the below code?

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="demo"></div>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'api',
})

var TodoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TodoItem,
    url: 'api/todos'
})

var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('<h3> ' +'<input type=checkbox ' +'<% if(status === "complete") print("checked") %>/>' +' <%= description %></h3>'),
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()))
    }

})

var TodoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.collection,'reset',this.render)
        this.collection.fetch({reset:true})
    },
    render: function(){
        console.log(this.collection.length)
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne,this)
    },
    addOne: function(todoItem){
        console.log(todoItem.get('description'))
        var todoView = new TodoView({model: todoItem})
        this.$el.append(todoView.render())
    }

})


var todoItem = new TodoItem()
var todoList = new TodoCollection()

var todoListView = new TodoListView({el: '#demo', collection: todoList})

todoListView.render()

console.log(todoListView.el)


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Here is the CONSOLE output Iam getting:**

```
0 
<div id=​"demo">​</div>​     
3 
pick up cookies
Milk 
Cookies
```

Comment: Could you add a tryable example?

Comment: `and Iam not sure why '3' and 'Descriptions' got displayed later` - Because it the result of a async Ajax requeste.

Try to change this: `this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()))` with `this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes))`

Comment: @Frogmouth Still same result iam getting

Comment: Any more replies please....

Answer (score 1):

For starters you might want to take out the {reset: true} from your fetch.
A fetch wil automatically clear the model/collection anyway.

Please also use semicolons at the end of your command, not using them will let the browser interpret where the semicolon should be. This takes time and is error prone (the browser might just place it where you didn't think it would).

if this does not work you might want to do add the fetch into the render doing this:

```
render: function(){

    var that = this;

    this.collection.fetch().done(function(data) {

        console.log(that.collection.length);
        that.collection.forEach(that.addOne,that);

    });

},
```

What also might work, but you need to test this, I personally always use the one above:

```
render: function(){

    this.collection.fetch().done(function(data) {

        console.log(this.collection.length);
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne,this);

    }, this);

},
```

Comment: Let us know if this is the correct answer for you ;)

Comment: Hi , I just tried your above code, iam getting error as : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: hey @user3815806 I forgot to pass the this to the function. Please try again with above script!

Comment: The `reset:true` is needed to get `fetch` to trigger a `'reset'` event and thus trigger the initial `render` call. Calling `fetch` inside `render` seems a bit bizarre to me, wouldn't it be better to `this.collection.fetch().done(this.render.bind(this))` inside `initialize`?

Comment: I wouldn't call it bizarre, it depends on the way you set your view. 
In the case above he is calling the render seperately in his code. In my opinion this as a good practice because you only render when you need it. 
Running the fetch in the render works. Thouhg it's indeed a bit 'unstructured'. 
In most cases, you'd probably run render immediatly after setting the view. So then call the render from within the initialize is a good practice, maybe the best one. 
Don't know but this might work as well: 
var todoListView = new TodoListView({el: '#demo', collection: todoList}).done(this.render);

Answer (score 0):

and Iam not sure why '3' and 'Descriptions' got displayed later - Because it the result of a async Ajax request.

now, try to change your code (watch comment):

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('<h3> ' +'<input type=checkbox ' +'<% if(status === "complete") print("checked") %>/>' +' <%= description %></h3>'),
    clearItem : function(){
         this.$el.find("h3").remove();
    },
    render: function(){
        //all DOM manipulation in view
        this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    }

})

var TodoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        // split "reset" event and "add" event
        this.listenTo(this.collection,'reset',this.removeAll);
        this.listenTo(this.collection,'add',this.addOne);
        this.collection.fetch({reset:true});
    },

    removeAll : function(){
        //method to remove all element from view
        //your problem is that this event will fire before ajax request done
        console.log("reset!");
        var todoView = new TodoView();
        todoView.clearItem();
    },

    addOne: function(todoItem){
        //fire when a model in the collection change (automatic after fetch result) for each model.
        console.log("add ITEM:",todoItem);
        var todoView = new TodoView({model: todoItem})
        todoView.render();
    }

});
```

**NOTE**: Remove `todoListView.render()` in your code.

Sorry but, my english is too bad. I do not have time to explain better. Try if my code work

- EVENTS in backbone: http://backbonejs.org/#Events
- FETCH in collection: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch
- RENDER a view: http://backbonejs.org/#View-render